# Is the column space of $A$ contained within the column space of $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices with the same number of rows. How can we determine if the column space of $A$ is contained within the column space of $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column space of $A$ is contained within the column space of $B$ if and only if each of the columns $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are contained with the column space of $B$, which is true if and only if $Bx = a_i$ has a solution for each column $a_1,\dots,a_n$ of $A$.

It follows that a reasonable way to answer this question is to row-reduce the augmented matrix $[B \mid A]$. The column space of $A$ is contained within the column space of $B$ if and only if no pivots appear in the columns of $A$.